# External JIRA Gadget throwing error 'The resource /rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapid/charts/velocity?rapidViewId=some_id, cannot be found.'

Tags: jquery, jira, jira-rest-api, google-gadget

I am trying to access the custom JIRA gadget in Confluence. The application link was made between the JIRA and Confluence. After then I have added the link under external gadget section for the JIRA gadget ex.-"https://JIRA_Base_URL/rest/gadgets/1.0/g/jira-gadget-tutorial-plugin:tutorial-gadget/gadget.xml". When i am trying to add macro in the confluence page, it throws me an error saying that "The resource /rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapid/charts/velocity?rapidViewId=some_id, cannot be found." 
What can be the cause of this problem? Is there any settings need to be done? or something else need to do? [The image shows how i am getting the error in the macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N0sB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it is not a solution, but a hint from my installation.

The other application (confluence in your case) needs to verify the JIRA's certificate to use https access. To do it, it may need an intermediate (and root) certificates.

In the case these are not available in the Java default keystore the connection is not possible (you see an error message in the log on inability to build a certificate chain).

You may either add the necessary certificate (downloaded by your browser when accessing the JIRA instance) to the JVM keystore of the confluence instance or create a new one and point to it in a property like:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/myCacert -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=

placed in bin/setenv.sh of the confluence installation or by adding to service properties on Windows.

Comment: I probably didn't recognize in time that the 'less than' and 'greater then' character are recognized as special characters and stripped off. The 'path to' and 'password' disappeared from the properties values...